# C# 2D array indexes exchange

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, keyevent

I have 2D array.

for example:

```
        int[,] Map = new int[5, 5]
        { 
        {1,1,1,1,1},
        {1,2,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,0,0,0,1},
        {1,1,1,1,1}
        };
```

And I need on some KeyEvent change index of number 2 (index - [1,1]).

for example:

```
        1,1,1,1,1
        1,0,2,0,1
        1,0,0,0,1
        1,0,0,0,1
        1,1,1,1,1
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You want to swap two array items. What did you try? This is a very easy problem. You should be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with? What have you tried?

Comment: also, a simple search yields several solutions

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent piece of documentation in the form of an article available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).
It gives an in-depth explanation of the entire process for handling multidimensional arrays including the following code for managing your array:

```
// Initialization
int[,] array = new int[4, 2];
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

// Modification
array2D[1, 1] = 8;

// Access
Console.WriteLine(array2D[2,1]);
```

In the example above for modification, it will change the second (using a zero-based index) item's second integer to the value of 8.

In the example above for accessing, it will display the third item's second integer which will return 6.

To directly answer your question, the concept of "exchanging" variables involves three steps:

1. Using an accessor to set the value of a temporary variable for the first value
2. Using a setter and an accessor to set the first value to the second value
3. Using a setter to set the second value to the temporary variable's value

An example of this working would be:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
int temp;
temp = a; // Step 1
a = b; // Step 2
b = temp; // Step 3
```

With the example you've given, it appears that you're setting the third item in the second array to the second item in the second array. This procedure can be done using the following:

```
int temp;
temp = map[1, 2];
map[1, 2] = map[1, 1];
map[1, 1] = temp;
```